# Issues with secant root-finding function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've been messing around with this function for a while now and I can't seem to find a way around the issue I'm having.

My code is:

```
function [x,i] = secant(f, x0, x1, tol, maxiters)
%SECANT Secant method
% [X,I] = SECANT(F, X0, X1, TOL, MAXITERS) performs the secant
% method with F(x), starting at x_0 = X0 and x_1 = X1, and continuing
% until either |X_i+1 - X_i| <= TOL, or MAXITERS iterations have
% been taken. The number of iterations, I, is also returned.
% An error is raised if the first input is not a function handle.
% A warning is raised if the maximum number of iterations is reached
% without achieving the tolerance.

if ~isa(f, 'function_handle')
error('Your first input was not a function handle')
end

i = 0; % initialise iterate counter
x = x1;
x_old = x0; 
while abs(x - x_old) > tol && i < maxiters
x_old = x0;
x = x - f(x)*(x - x_old)/(f(x) - f(x_old)); % compute the new x
i = i + 1; % increase our counter by one

end
if abs(x - x_old) > tol
warning('Maximum number of iterations reached without achieving tolerance.')
end
```

When I run the code I don't get the same answer as I do by hand. Currently I'm using,

```
f = @(x) 0.9cos(x) - sqrt(x)

x0 = 0

x1 = 1

tol = 1e-08

maxiters = 4
```

I believe my issues is coming from the line `x_old = x0;` which is underneath `while abs(x - x_old) > tol && i < maxiters`.I think every time I call the function, it sets `x` back to `x0`.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as you mentioned. x_old is always set to 0 when in fact it should be set to x_i-2 for every iteration i. This is the relevant code you need to change

```
i = 0; % initialise iterate counter
%Store the initial values in a different variable
x_0 = x0;
x_1 = x1;
while abs(x - x_old) > tol && i < maxiters
    x = x_1 - f(x_1) * (x_1 - x_0)/(f(x_1) - f(x_0)); % compute the new x
    % Update the previous values
    x_0 = x_1;
    x_1 = x;
    i = i + 1; % increase our counter by one
end
```